# Meteor Autoform pushArray with nested schema

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm using [autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) for meteor. I have an array of nested schemas, like so:

```
addresses: {
  type: [Schemas.address],
  optional: true,
  defaultValue: []
}
```

and I'm attempting to add an address to the array using `update-pushArray`

```
{{> quickForm id="myformid" type="update-pushArray" doc=getDocument collection=getCollection scope="addresses"}}
```

But I'm getting these gems:

```
MinimongoError: Cannot apply $push modifier to non-array

"MongoError: The field 'addresses' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: "383EfPJgeZQJFgs72"} [409]"
```

So I tried wrapping it in an array in a `formToDoc` hook:

```
SimpleSchema.clean: filtered out value that would have affected key "0", which is not allowed by the schema
```

So... yeah. That's the limit of my fresh ideas. What do you have?

Comment: It looks like there was an issue with the update-pushArray type until a few days after you posted this question. According to aldeed you need to be running Autoform 5.0.2 and Meteor 1.0.3.1 or higher for it to work.  https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/788. Also, aldeed posted a sample that might help http://autoform.meteor.com/updatepush

Comment: @BrianShamblen post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there was an issue with the update-pushArray type until a few days after you posted this question. According to aldeed you need to be running Autoform 5.0.2 and Meteor 1.0.3.1 or higher for it to work. http://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/788. Also, aldeed posted a sample that might help http://autoform.meteor.com/updatepush